# Setting the ShapeAppearanceOverlay programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I am using Material.io for a ShapeableImageView. Now I would like to set the shapeAppearanceOverlay programmatically. In XML it would look like this:

```
app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageView"
```

I cannot find a function to set the shapeAppearanceOverlay. Do you have any idea how I can set it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `ShapeAppearanceOverlay::setShapeAppearanceModel`, like so:

```kotlin
val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.some_corner_radius)
val shapeAppearanceModel = imageView.shapeAppearanceModel.toBuilder()
    .setAllCornerSizes(radius)
    .build()
circleShapeImageView.imageView = shapeAppearanceModel
```

Take a look at the [`ShapeableImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView#setShapeAppearanceModel(com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearanceModel)) and [`ShapeAppearanceModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/ShapeAppearanceModel) documentation.